# How to change the text color based on a value using php and html?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I have 2 values $minsRecoded and $totalMins and I would like if the minsRecorded is greater the the totalMins then display $totalMinsComplted in a danger badge.

Here is what I have in my controller

```
$sumMins = \App\ProjectTimeLog::where('user_id', '=', '1')->pluck('total_minutes')->sum()/60;
  $minsRecoded = Task::getTotalMinsCompleted()/60;


  $totalMin = \App\ProjectTimeLog::where('user_id', '=', '1')->pluck('total_minutes')->sum()/60;
  $this->totalMins = \App\ProjectTimeLog::where('user_id', '=', '1')->pluck('total_minutes')->sum()/60;

if ($minsRecoded < $totalMin) $this->totalMinsCompleted = '<span class="badge badge-danger">";
```

Here is my view

```
 {{$totalMinsCompleted}}/{{$totalMins}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the badge using `.=`. This will keep the original content and append the badge to it, when the if condition is true.

```
if ($minsRecoded < $totalMin) $this->totalMinsCompleted .= '<span class="badge badge-danger">';
```

Comment: for a default badge or something else you can concat totalMinsCompleted like that  $this->totalMinsCompleted .= ($minsRecoded < $totalMin) ? '<span class="badge badge-danger">' : '<span class="badge badge-something">';